# how to provide download option for the dynamically generated file in java

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

I am creating pdf file using jasper reports. The code for generating the pdf file runs fine and the file is created on a specified path. But I want the file to be downloaded rather than to be stored on some drive of a client. I use word dynamically in my question because it is generated from jasper reports when user clicks on download. I googled for this and I got that response.setHeader is responsible for downloading but it needs a source or we can say that path of the storage. The code for generating pdf is given below.

```
String ip="D:\\workspace\\Jsaper1\\src\\Coll.jasper";
    String op="D:\\workspace\\Jsaper1\\src\\Timesheet.pdf";


    try
    {
        File file=new File(ip);
        InputStream is=new FileInputStream(file);
         Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Datasource da=new Datasource();
        JRDataSource jrdsource=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(da.getDataSource());


        JasperReport jreport=(JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(file);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jreport, params, da.getDataSource1());

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, op);   

                sos.flush();
        sos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the generated file is already written in the disk, you can just open it then write to the response' `OutputStream`. Use `IOUtils#copy` from Apache to copy the content of input stream to an output stream avoiding the boilerplate. It also does internal buffering so no need to wrap your `InputStream` with `BufferedInputStream`.

```
public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream; charset=windows-1252");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(new File("file-path-where-generated-pdf-is-stored"));
            output = response.getOutputStream();

            IOUtils.copy(input, output);

            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log it
        } finally{
            close(input);
            close(output);

            input = null;
            output = null;
        }
    }

    //Right way to close resource
    public static void close(Closeable c) {
        if (c == null) return; 
        try {
            c.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            //log it
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a solution for you**

Insert this code in your html/Interface file. You could do something like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.pdf");
ServletOutputStream sosStream = response.getOutputStream();
JasperPrint jasperPrint = (JasperPrint) session.getAttribute("jasperPrint");
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, sosStream);
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("TempFile.pdf",".tmp",new File("."));
InputStream isStream = null;
isStream = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
int ibit = 256;
while ((ibit) >= 0)
 {
            ibit = isStream.read();
            sosStream.write(ibit);
 }
sosStream.flush();
sosStream.close();
isStream.close();
out.clear();
out = pageContext.pushBody();
```

Notes :- 
1. Response contentype and Header is set. 
2. You can set jasperprint in session and retrieve it. 
3. JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream is called on the fly. This will take create an outpoutstream of pdf. 
4. Rest of the code does writing jobs from stream to temp file.

You can call this code on click action of a button for download and a pop-up for download file will emerge asking for save location.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below sample as reference

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JRAbstractExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = exporter.exportReport();
OutputStream os = null;

try {
   response.setContentType(mimeType);
   response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Timesheet.pdf");
   response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
   response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
   os = response.getOutputStream();
   response.setContentLength(baos.size());

   baos.writeTo(os);
  }  finally {
        os.flush();
        os.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use ByteArrayOutputStream obj in report method  , I have implemented in Dynamic report(Jasper Api) , Its working for me :-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pdfDownload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getPdfDownload(HttpServletResponse response) {
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

report().columns().setDataSource().show()
.toPdf(buffer);

byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream (bytes);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Accepted1.pdf");
response.flushBuffer();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use bellow code. Here is complete Example using java servlet**

I have add bellow code. you can use bellow code to download pdf file from servlet..

1. Please download bellow jar file
   Please download bellow jar file

   ```
   1. jasperreports-5.0.1.jar
   2. commons-logging-1.1.2.jar
   3. commons-digester-2.1.jar
   4. commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar
   5. commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
   6. groovy-all-2.1.3.jar
   7. com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar
   8. your database library
   ```
2. Now use bellow code in servlet in doGet

   ```
   @Override
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException {   
   try {
       String path = "D:\\Software\\iReport-5.0.0-windows-installer\\u\\report4.jrxml";
       JasperReport jasReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path);
       System.out.println("Jasper Report : " + jasReport);
        //Database connection
       Connection con = /*Your Datase Connection*/ ;
       System.out.println(con);
       //If You have paramerter add here
       Map paramMap = new HashMap();
       paramMap.put("id", request.getParameter("id"));

       //if your have any parmeter add null to paramMap
       JasperPrint jasPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasReport, null, con); //, mapParam, con);
       System.out.println("Jasper Print : " + jasPrint);

       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

       response.setContentType("application/x-download");
       response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=creditcard.pdf");
       ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
       JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasPrint, sos);

   } catch (JRException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Tests.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
   }
   ```